# How to reduce vibration on aluminum quadcopter?

Tags: vibrations

I have an aluminum quadcopter with that's made of thin aluminum and its really flimsy. And there is lot of vibration when I fly it. My question is, if I make the frame stiffer so it doesn't bend, will it reduce vibrations. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making the frame stiffer and lighter will shift the modes to higher and higher frequencies, possibly beyond the excitation frequencies induced by your thruster motors. - so yes.

But another method is to provide a means of absorbing the vibrational energy with material that can act as a damper. One material comes to mind - [sorbothane](http://www.sorbothane.com/) which I used in a project to passively isolate high frequency from a gimbal mount on an aircraft.

But for your quadrotor the best way would be to stiffen and lighten thus providing more payload capacity. There are two ways to stiffen (1) by structural design and (2) choice of material. Higher grade aluminum like 6061-T6 provides the best stiffness, but graphite composites would serve you better if you can afford the extra expense and effort fabricating.

Comment: Thanks! So graphite composite would be better right? And what is the difference between graphite composite vs carbon fiber?